# usepackage{siunitx} produces error - texstudio

Tags: errors, miktex, siunitx

Im using TexStudio in UTF8. the following codes

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
    \num{0.12368455}

    \num[round-mode=places,round-precision=4]{0.12368455}
\end{document}
```

are producing the error

> siunitx.sty Line 258 Undefined control sequence }
>
> siunitx.sty Line 258 Missing \begin{document} }

I used the package siunitx the first time, so i had to install it via the auto-window after running the file. 
Then i deletet the package and reinstalled it via miktex-package-manager (as admin). I got the same error.

Someone have an idea?

Comment: Make sure you thoroughly update MiKTeX both in admin and user mode.

Comment: Miktex installation is split into two modes, admin and user. User takes precedence. Meaning if you installed a package on the fly, it probably goes into user mode. If later on you install a newer version ad admin, it is still the user mode installed version that is being used. Therefore, if you are a miktex user: always update as admin **and** user.

Comment: Just for the record: The example compiles fine for me on a MikTeX installation updated this morning. Unfortunately, the error messages are shortened and do crucially not show the undefined control sequence, so there is not a lot to go by here. But with MikTeX systems it is always a good first guess to recommend a thorough update in both admin *and* user mode (ideally twice, to be sure). See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108447/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/35864.